# Should I delete a twice upvoted and twice downvoted answer?

Tags: discussion

Few months ago I answered a question, which seemed to be helpful and I received two upvotes, resulting in +20. Some days later I got two downvotes for the same answer, resulting in -4.

That means I still got +16, but as you should not just help here just for reputation

-> should I delete the answer, because the newer reactions were negative?

Comment: What does OP say? Was that answer helpful for him? Have you got a comment about the downvote reasons? Do you see something that could be improved in your answer? Don't just delete posts on a downvote, try to fix/improve them first.

Comment: You got two comments on the answer explaining why people downvoted it. Do you agree with their comments? If not, is it possible to clarify your answer in a way that addresses those comments? If you don't agree, did you consider responding? (Not that much point *now*, as the comments are now 9 months old).

Comment: Since I agree with them, I assume you advice me to delete the answer?

Comment: If you *feel* that your answer adds more to what is already offered, keep it. If you think future programmers will be better off if they read your answer, keep it. If not, see if you can improve it and keep in mind that your answer not be a duplicate of another one. If that also is not possible, go ahead, delete it.

Comment: Yes I feel it adds something, the first two votes were positive and there's no other answer. I might wait for more reactions, and decide then. Does this sound rational?

Comment: I'd probably wait it out.

Comment: I found the answer you're talking about. It has two comments telling you that your answer is incorrect. So in that case your answer wouldn't be useful.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the badge. I'll delete it.

Comment: @danny not a problem. It's a shame really as it could have potentially fixed the problem. With questions like this often a guess is all you can do unless you really know how the code works. The problem with guessing is if it's wrong you'll receive downvotes. Better to clarify with the OP first in the comments and then provide an answer. Don't let it deter you from answering other questions though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say you've probably been a little premature with your answer here. It doesn't solve the problem because the error doesn't lie on the `For i = 0 To UBound(SheetNames)` statement it lies here; `Worksheets(SheetNames(i))` and so really the OP needs to determine if `Worksheets("MV1")` actually exists along with the other entries in `SheetNames`.

The OP *should* have included that in their question rather than as a comment on your answer but that's why [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) left a comment for the OP.

Additionally [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) does have a gold badge in the VBA tag which usually means they know what they are talking about.

I would consider deleting.